# OC4J application server

Tags: java

i am using OC4J application server and struts framework the issue is i am setting value in request attributes during action servlet process then it goes to tag custom java class here request attributes comes null. is it due to jar file missing.

Comment: What jar-file do you mean? Mainly it is possible if this jar just a plugin and the plugin system just setting the null to the field (I suppose that plugin injected through DI). In other cases you must have error ClassNotFound or something similar

Comment: i am not sure because of jar file. httpservletrequest are recreated between requests so the issue is i am setting attributes value in request at struts action servlet then it goes to tag custom java class here it is null

Comment: I'm sorry, it is very hard to me to understand your last sentence. What is your native language? Do you speak Russian? If yes we can continue through Google+, if not - then please rewrite the sentence with commas.